# Neovim slow while compiling LaTeX

Tags: neovim, plugin-vimtex

When I compile a .tex file using vimtex it takes a hot second to compile.
Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213597/how-to-see-which-plugins-are-making-vim-slow) I obtained the profile.log while compiling latex [given below is just the sorted part]

```
FUNCTIONS SORTED ON TOTAL TIME
count  total (s)   self (s)  function
   98   0.032380   0.007479  <SNR>67_callback_nvim_output()
   98   0.024283   0.000995  <SNR>67_check_callback()
    2   0.023288   0.000245  vimtex#compiler#callback()
    1   0.019037   0.000420  vimtex#qf#open()
    1   0.018603   0.000142  vimtex#qf#setqflist()
    1   0.013933   0.000048  81()
    9   0.013894   0.000996  213()
    1   0.011376   0.000215  82()
    9   0.010779   0.000460  vimtex#delim#get_current()
    9   0.010318   0.008323  <SNR>89_get_delim()
   13   0.008096             <SNR>11_try()
    3   0.007438   0.003553  <SNR>69_fix_paths_hbox_warning()
   20   0.006732   0.006130  <SNR>26_Highlight_Matching_Pair()
  320   0.003881             vimtex#util#count()
    2   0.002816   0.002683  <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin()
    1   0.002509   0.002179  vimtex#qf#u#caddfile()
    1   0.002242   0.000010  vimtex#log#info()
    1   0.002232   0.000183  206()
    1   0.001921   0.001388  vimtex#debug#stacktrace()
    1   0.001615   0.001522  18()

FUNCTIONS SORTED ON SELF TIME
count  total (s)   self (s)  function
    9   0.010318   0.008323  <SNR>89_get_delim()
   13              0.008096  <SNR>11_try()
   98   0.032380   0.007479  <SNR>67_callback_nvim_output()
   20   0.006732   0.006130  <SNR>26_Highlight_Matching_Pair()
  320              0.003881  vimtex#util#count()
    3   0.007438   0.003553  <SNR>69_fix_paths_hbox_warning()
    2   0.002816   0.002683  <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin()
    1   0.002509   0.002179  vimtex#qf#u#caddfile()
    1   0.001615   0.001522  18()
    1   0.001921   0.001388  vimtex#debug#stacktrace()
    2   0.001377   0.001294  <SNR>43_SynSet()
    9   0.013894   0.000996  213()
   98   0.024283   0.000995  <SNR>67_check_callback()
    9              0.000815  vimtex#syntax#stack()
    9              0.000734  212()
    9              0.000667  <SNR>101_parse_args()
    9              0.000644  197()
   20              0.000602  <SNR>26_Remove_Matches()
    6              0.000533  vimtex#util#command()
    2              0.000474  <SNR>2_LoadIndent()
```

None of the above look awfully slow, and I am a bit stumped on how to proceed further.

What I tried:

- I tried  turning off relative line numbers, cursorline and folding as these were known to cause lag in tex files

What I require

- some optimization for VimTex to compile faster
- some other alternative (my only requirement is that my pdf auto-updates when I `:write` or give errors in case compilation fails)

My vimtex config is just default configuration

```
return{
'lervag/vimtex',
ft={"tex"}
}
```

I have also asked this question here
https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/16v879n/help_vimtex_compilation_slow_on_nvim/

Comment: While editing I removed what looked like an accidentally duplicated copy-paste in the code, but please restore it if it was intended.

Comment: First: Don't lazy load VimTeX! That is, remove `ft={"tex"}`. You don't need it and it breaks a feature that requires global presence.

Comment: Now, except for that: I don't think VimTeX should lead to the slowdown you report here, but it is impossible to provide an answer based on the current input. My suspicion is that there are other things at play. But what it is is hard to say!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running latexmk from terminal [latexmk -pdf -pvc main.tex] results in similar compilation times to vimtex. So I think there is nothing wrong with vimtex

The reason I thought vimtex was slow is because if I compile using the command:

> pdflatex main.tex

The compilation was almost instantaneous.

Apologies, I realize now there is no fault in vimtex

Comment: `latexmk` does more than just `pdflatex` to make sure it compiles everything correctly (typical compilations run `pdflatex` 2 to 3 times, in addition to things like bibliography tools).